# Problems generating Google App Engine Backend in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, maven, android-studio

I'm not able to use the backend generation feature in the Android Studio. I followed [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html) blog post trying to set up a backend for my application, however I'm getting the following IDE error:

Exception in plugin Maven Integration

```
Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/util/containers/ContainerUtil.map must not be null: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/util/containers/ContainerUtil.map must not be null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/util/containers/ContainerUtil.map must not be null
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.map(ContainerUtil.java)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.collectFiles(MavenUtil.java:247)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenProjectBuilder.commit(MavenProjectBuilder.java:129)
    at com.intellij.projectImport.ProjectImportBuilder.commit(ProjectImportBuilder.java:59)
    at com.google.gct.intellij.endpoints.externalbuilder.MavenBackendGeneratorHelper.addMavenFunctionality(MavenBackendGeneratorHelper.java:216)
    at com.google.gct.intellij.endpoints.externalbuilder.ui.GenerateMavenBackend.actionPerformed(GenerateMavenBackend.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:260)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:892)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:230)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:104)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:512)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:44)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:532)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:686)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:510)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:339)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

After the process finishes, I only get the -AppEngine module generated, with no -endpoints module.

I'm sure that Maven is set up properly on my machine, I checked with [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57193) issue that also complains about not being able to generate the backend.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: @jiduvah, Nope, unfortunately..

Comment: @Egor Thanks for the question.  I've tried 2 versions of Ubuntu and 2 versions of Windows with no success.  Do you know the command to generate the back end or how to generate it?  It might be easier to understand debug if we all run the same (or similar) script rather than the random "point and click testing" :)

Answer (score 1):

[windows 8] get 0.4.0 Android Studio,
New Project,
click on the  to select
Tools>Google Cloud Tools>Generate App Engine

provide Project Number and Project ID and API Key, from
https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
looks like you already know about this

This will generate -AppEngine
and
-endpoints

Select -endpoints on the left Project browser,
then Tools>Google Cloud Tools>Generate Client Libraries 
(this makes the .war that get deployed with app-engine so app-engine code can deal with endpoint code)

Click on "Maven Projects" written vertically on the far right top,
click Plugins>appengine, click appengine:update

That will deploy the appengine.

(Jan 7 '14) You have to go back to the console and reselect the correct Version in order for the app to Register with the Endpoint Service.

go here:
https://cloud.google.com/console#/project, then click AppEngine, then click Versions, then click the latest Version, then click Make Default

Comment: I am using 0.5.2 and don't have a Tools>Google Cloud Tools>Generate App Engine, do you know how it changed?

Comment: It's named different for me too

Comment: I have File>New Module>Google Cloud Module>AppEngine Java Endpoints Module but otherwise I have tested and confirmed that it works

Answer (score 1):

The new solution is to go to **File**>**New Module**>**More Modules**>**AppEngine Java Endpoints Module**

Here's a Google I/O video that describes more about setting up the steps to set it up:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBhOkfbbZLk

There's also this link on Google's documentation for Cloud Tools:
https://cloud.google.com/mobile/app_engine/add_module

Answer (score 0):

You Should Need to Install the Google API Packages into Your Workspace..Then,only You will Access the same..Otherwise,it shows an ERROR only..