# Android studio - Invalid App-Engine SDK Path

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I am trying to run my first android application in Android studio. Application created successfully with new project vizard but cant run that as getting this error--

Invalid App-Engine SDK Path

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is the problem--

**exception in plugin Google cloud tools for android studio**

After disabling this plugin its working now!!

In other scenario if you want to setup Google app engine this might help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20986031/472336

Comment: I don't know why that problem was there but once I connected  device or create any AVD that bug was not there

Answer (score 6):

All answers about disabling the plugin are incorrect.

You need to execute `./gradlew appengineDownloadSdk` in the root of your project. Alternatively you can execute the task via the gradle sidebar in Android Studio.

This task will create the folders given the current versions in your `build.gradle` file. You have to run this when you update versions in your dependency list.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to disable the Google Cloud Tools for Android Studio plugin.

In Android Studio, click on:

**File > Settings**

Then click on **Plugins** (on the left), and uncheck **"Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio"**. Then **Apply**.

It asks you to restart Android Studio. Click on **Restart** and it will work now.

Answer (score 0):

I've created folder

```
c:\Users\[user_name]\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\
```

And copy sdk that download there

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

So currently project compiles and works for me