# Invalid App Engine SDK Path - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have a large project that works great using Eclipse. So I am trying to see how it works in AS.

No errors on compiling. But when I click on debug I get a popup EDIT CONFIGURATION. It wants the path to the App Engine SDK among other things.  I have no idea what its wanting or what to enter in the edit box.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html), it is something that is automatically downloaded when you create a cloud project. Since you brought your project over from Eclipse, it seems you need to [install it yourself](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads) and point to that location.

If you are not using cloud services, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631727/android-studio-invalid-app-engine-sdk-path) indicates you might get rid of the dependency by disabling the plugin "Google cloud tools for android studio".

Comment: THANK YOU! I searched for hours trying to find something.  I really appreciate the effort and time.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the folder where you have your SDK.

File - Project Structure - Project Structure - SDK Location

So it depends on where you downloaded the SDK you are using or used to use with Eclipse. I've put mine in C:\Program Files\Eclipse and SDK\sdk

Additionally you could read [Getting Started with Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) and [Migrating from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)